# ¿ Como generar salida con colores desde shell script bash a archivo y mantener los colores?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Estoy desarrollando una utilidad en un shell script bash (archivo.sh), puedo generar colores cuando la salida va a consola, por ejemplo con un código como:

```
echo -e "\e[1;33m Aqui el mensaje \e[0m";
```

Pero mi idea es crear un archivo log lo mas idéntico posible a la salida que emito por consola, por lo cual me gustaría tener el texto en colores también en el archivo log. Estoy utilizando esta sentencia para emitir tanto a consola como al archivo log:

```
echo -e "\e[1;33m Aqui el mensaje \e[0m" 2>&1 | tee --append $nombreArchivo;
```

El comando '**tee**' es quien hace posible que el flujo de entrada vaya a consola y al archivo de log.

El problema con esto es que en el archivo de log los caracteres '**\e[1;33m**' por ejemplo, no son interpretados, por lo cual esos caracteres se escriben tal cual en el archivo y se ve horroroso; pero supongo que si debe ser posible porque el comando '**ls -l 2>&1 | tee --append $nombreArchivo**' si escribe en el archivo los colores del comando '**ls**' tal cual los emite por consola.

Supongo que hay que usar una nomenclatura distinta para utilizar los colores, pero la desconozco.

Acá la salida de '**ls -l**' con color, por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo bien tu requerimiento. Esto `"\e[1;33m Aqui el mensaje \e[0m"` va al archivo tal cual está escrito, los códigos ANSI solo son válidos para la consola, es decir, para reproducir los colores deberías hacer `cat archivo.log`. Si vas a abrir estos archivos con cualquier otro utilitario o editor, solo verás el código ANSI crudo. Te comento también que `echo -e "\e[1;33m Aqui el mensaje \e[0m" 2>&1 | tee --append $nombreArchivo; cat $nombreArchivo` me muestra correctamente los colores por consola

Comment: Si el comando con tee muestra normal los colores por consola, pero que idea tienes para enviar los mismos mensajes con los mismos colores pero al archivo? lo que quiero es enviar los mismos colores que envío a la consola, al archivo

Comment: Es que los códigos ANSI ya se los estás enviando al archivo perfectamente, si abres el LOG con un editor de texto, obviamente, solo verás los códigos crudos, el editor no puede interpretarlos como un color en particular, si quieres ver realmente los colores los tienes que imprimir nuevamente por la consola `cat archivo.log`.

Comment: pero porque entonces cuando envío 'ls -l' y luego observo el archivo, los colores están ? es decir algo hace ese comando que si pinta los caracteres en el archivo.

Comment: ¿Con que abres el archivo? si lo vuelves a visualizar por consola, es la consola la que interpreta los códigos del archivo y lo vuelve a mostrar en colores.

Comment: lo se, esos codigos son interpretados por la consola y por eso aparece el texto con color, yo lo que quiero es tener el mismo efecto en un archivo de texto plano, cuando haces lo que yo pretendo hacer pero con el comando 'ls -l' el archivo si aparece con el texto en colores como lo hace ese comando por consola

Comment: Es que no puedes, un archivo de texto plano, es justamente eso, texto plano, sin ningún tipo de formato. Puedes enviar los código de color como lo estás haciendo, pero cuando abras el archivo con un editor, verás esos códigos no el cambio de color que esperas. Necesitarías un programa que pueda interpretar esos códigos como lo hace la consola, de hecho la forma natural de ver la salida en color es enviar el archivo a la consola, por ej: `cat archivo.log`

Comment: te entiendo, pero que me dices de lo que te digo del comandio 'ls -l' ?

Comment: Primero que nada depende de la distribución de linux, en este caso`ls -l` se ve que genera códigos de color ANSI que son enviados a la salida estándar que luego procesa la consola y te los muestra como colores, pero  si rediriges la misma salida a un archivo de texto la salida serán los códigos (no los colores). Es siempre la consola la que interpreta los códigos y te muestra los colores.

Comment: @RicardoGabriel ¿Podrías compartir una captura de pantalla de cómo se ve ese supuesto archivo de texto plano coloreado?

Comment: @nxnev edite la pregunta para colocar la captura de pantalla, allí la puedes ver

Comment: @RicardoGabriel Ya veo. ¿Podrías compartir otras dos capturas? Una con el archivo abierto en un editor sin coloreo de sintaxis (como el bloc de notas) y otra donde se muestre la salida de `ls -l` en la terminal.

Comment: @nxnev en ese caso no aparece con colores, yo solo quiero que se vea tal cual se ve en vscode, no es necesario convencerme de que un archivo de texto plano no interpreta los códigos especiales de la consola, eso lo se, solo quiero una salida con colores en vscode, con eso estaría excelente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un pequeño error de concepto el cual, creo yo, es la causa de la confusión.

**Los colores de la salida de `ls -l` que se ven en Visual Studio Code no son producto de una nomenclatura especial propia del comando que se pueda replicar desde un script de shell.**

Puedes darte cuenta de ello porque si abres el archivo en un editor más simple el color no se muestra, además de las discrepancias que hay en el coloreo (en la columna de fecha, "2018" está en azul y las horas en verde; los nombres de archivo no se colorean al completo, solo la parte de `nombre.ext` para los que cuentan con extensión) y porque `ls` únicamente colorea los nombres de archivo de acuerdo a su tipo (al menos en la implementación de GNU).

**Lo que en realidad ocurre es que VS Code está agregando [resaltado de sintaxis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resaltado_de_sintaxis) por su propia cuenta.** Desconozco en qué lenguaje está interpretando el texto (quizá sea algún tipo de resaltado genérico), pero definitivamente no es algo que puedas usar a tu conveniencia de manera arbitraria sin antes modificar el editor mismo.

En un comentario anterior mencioné que mi recomendación era añadir un resaltado de sintaxis personalizado a tu editor, pero pensándolo mejor no es muy buen consejo pues no aplica a casos arbitrarios y por cada cambio que hagas al script cabe la posibilidad de que también necesites modificar el resaltado.

**Las posibles soluciones dependen del propósito del archivo log:** ¿será procesado por otras herramientas o está pensado para ser únicamente de consumo humano?

**Si el archivo es o será procesado por otras herramientas** (`awk`, `grep`, `sed`, etc.): lo ideal será manterlo lo más simple posible (texto plano) para facilitar el procesamiento. En este caso, el color sería un obstáculo.

**Si el archivo va dirigido únicamente a las personas:** adapta la salida del archivo log al [lenguaje de marcado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_marcado) de tu preferencia y asegúrate de usar un intérprete apropiado para visualizar el archivo. En el caso de los [códigos de escape ANSI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI) (los que usaste en un principio), la terminal *es* el intérprete adecuado (no un editor de texto plano ni un IDE).

En el caso de HTML, hay terminales que te permiten guardar la información, color incluido, en este lenguaje (`xfce4-terminal`, por ejemplo). O podrías gestionarlo todo desde el propio script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

log='log.html'

printf '<!doctype html>\n' >> "${log}"
printf '<html>\n' >> "${log}"
printf '<head>\n' >> "${log}"
printf '<meta charset="utf-8"/>\n' >> "${log}"
printf '<title>¡Hola, mundo!</title>\n' >> "${log}"
printf '</head>\n' >> "${log}"
printf '<body style="background-color: #131926;">\n' >> "${log}"
printf '<pre>' >> "${log}"

# Este texto va hacia la terminal
printf '\e[1;32m¡Hola, mundo!\e[0m\n'

# Este texto va hacia el archivo log
printf '<strong style="color: #4CE64C;">¡Hola, mundo!</strong>\n' >> "${log}"

printf '</pre>\n' >> "${log}"
printf '</body>\n' >> "${log}"
printf '</html>\n' >> "${log}"
```

[image: Script de shell con color]