# ¿Como puedo cambiar el color de cada linea en este Script en Bash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, script

Mi objetivo seria que cada linea tuviera un color diferente, ahora mismo lo que hace mi script cambiar de color dependiendo la opcion que elijas, pero lo que yo quiero es que cada linea cambie de color por ejemplo:

```
echo "1.NTFS" (rojo)
echo "2.exFAT" (azul)
```

Y mi problema es que no se como aplicar el codigo.

El codigo de formateo es simplemente uno antiguo que he usado para intentar aplicar la funcion de cambiar los colores

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "di la particion a formatear: " PARTICION

echo "elige sistema de ficheros: "
echo "1. NTFS" 
echo "2. exFAT"
echo "3. HFS+"
echo "4. ext4"
echo "5. Salir"
read -p "introduce el numero de la opcion elegida: " OPCION


#if [ $OPCION <1 ] && [ $OPCION > 5 ] ; then
#   echo "Opcion no valida"
#   exit
#fi

case $OPCION in
    1) echo "Has elegido la opcion "$PARTICION" en el sistema NTFS"
       echo $(sudo mkfs -t ntfs $PARTICION | tput setaf 3);;

    2) echo "Has elegido la opcion "$PARTICION" en el sistema ext3"
       echo $(sudo mke2fs -t ext3 $PARTICION | tput setaf 2);;
    
    3) echo "Has elegido la opcion "$PARTICION" en el sistema HFS+"
       echo $(sudo mkfs.hfsplus $PARTICION | tput setaf 5);;

    4) echo "Has elegido la opcion "$PARTICION" en el sistema ext4"
       echo $(sudo mke2fs -t ext4 $PARTICION | tput setaf 6);;

    5) echo "Has detenido el script"
       exit;;
    *) echo "Opcion no valida... Deteniendo el script"
       exit;;
esac
```

Comment: recomiendo mirar [algún ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/210908/83) y dar a [edit] con lo que intentaste respecto a los colores en concreto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el color de texto (incluso el fondo y hasta el formato) puedes apoyarte en alguna de las dos opciones:

1. [Códigos de escape de color ANSI](https://dev.to/ifenna__/adding-colors-to-bash-scripts-48g4) -en inglés-.
2. Si está disponible, el comando [`tput`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php) -en inglés-.

Como verás en el siguiente ejemplo, uno es más dificil de implementar que el otro, todo depende la perspectiva, pero son sencillos de utilizar.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BOLD="\e[1m"
RED="\e[31m"
BLUE="\e[34m"
RESET="\e[0m"
BACK_GREEN="\e[102m"
BACK_YELLOW="\e[103m"
TPUT_BLUE=$(tput setaf 123)
TPUT_RESET=$(tput sgr0)
TPUT_BG_COLOR=$(tput setab 31)

read -e -p "${TPUT_BLUE}di la particion a formatear:${TPUT_RESET} " PARTICION

echo -e "${BACK_GREEN}Elige sistema de ficheros:${RESET} "
echo -e "${RED}1. NTFS${RESET}" 
echo -e "${BLUE}2. exFAT${RESET}"
echo "${TPUT_BLUE}3. HFS+${TPUT_RESET}"
echo "4. ext4"
echo "5. Salir"
echo "${TPUT_BG_COLOR}Particion: ${PARTICION}${TPUT_RESET}"
read -p "introduce el numero de la opcion elegida: " OPCION
```

Con lo anterior obtienes la siguiente salida:

[image: Salida]

Nota como al utilizar los códigos de escape, es necesario utilizar la opción -e en el comando `echo` ([más info](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/echoh.html) -en inglés- sobre lo que aquí se menciona).

> -e    habilita la interpretación de alguno de los siguientes escapes con diagonal invertida
>
> ...
>
> `echo` interpreta los siguientes caracteres escapados con diagonal invertida`
>
> ...
>
> \e    carácter de escape

Puedes darte una referencia de los cósigos de cada color en los links que te dejé, o simplemente usar tu tiempo para encontrar algún color que te agrade.